# AJAX Called PHP Query Not Working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax

I'm attempting to display dynamic data in a Bootstrap Modal using an AJAX call to a PHP query. The Javascript function is working fine and passing the ID to be used in the .php file, but the query itself doesn't seem to be working. I must be missing something pretty simple, but I don't get why it isn't working.

**SQL / PHP**
This file is being called and appears to be connecting to the db correctly, but the query itself isn't working.

```
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('omitted','omitted','omitted','omitted');
if (!$con)
{
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
 }


$sql = "SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE orderID = '".$q."'";
$result = mysql_query($con, $sql);
if (!$result) {
die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

No result is being returned, and no error message is coming back. A var_dump of all the variables used in this query returns the following: (When the die conditional is removed)

```
var_dump($q) = int(3) 
var_dump($sql) = string(40) "SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE orderID = '3'" 
var_dump($result) = bool(false)
```

Comment: What does `mysqli_error($con);` give on the query?

Comment: You're mixing mysqli functions and mysql_* functions. Switch everything to mysqli. And use parametrization!

Comment: Why are you mixing `mysql` with `mysqli`?

Comment: Thanks! I'm pretty new to this and was just reworking an example I found online. Changing everything to mysqli worked.

Comment: You want to call `mysqli_query` and `mysqli_error` (note the `i`).

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with `AJAX`. You are mixing `mysql` and `mysqli`.
Try the following -

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE orderID = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error());
}
```